# Can I use SSlogis as part of nls equation and how to find the coefficients of the SSlogis

Tags: r, nls, coefficients

I am trying a `nls` equation to predict soil respiration rate (SR). I use soil temperature, vegetation index and soil water content as the independent factors. I assume temperature (T10), vegetation index (VI) and soil water content (VWC) are correlated with R by exponential, linear and logistic, respectively. So my R codes is like

```
R1<-nls(SR ~ I(Rref*exp(log(Q)*T10) + a*VI+b+SSlogis(VWC,5,12,1)), 
             data=SR, start=list(Rref=0.82, Q=1.5, a=10, b=-1), 
             trace=T)
```

Rref is the respiration rate at 0 degree C, Q is the temperature sensitivity of respiration, a is the slope of the effect of vegetation index and b is the intercept of the respiration.

I assume the relationship between respiration and soil water content (VWC) is sigmoid (maybe saturation equation is good, too) since water only limits respiration when it is low (water deficit). The initial values of SSlogis coefficients were set as 5, 12, 1 based on the observation of the SR-VWC xyplot.

The model runs fine, but I can only see the values of Rref, Q, a and b from `summary` code.

```
Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Rref  1.71770    3.11436   0.552   0.5836    
Q     1.06064    0.05253  20.191   <2e-16 ***
a     8.47050    3.45392   2.452   0.0176 *  
b    -8.48737    3.50457  -2.422   0.0190 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.5 on 52 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 46 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.868e-06
```

How do I get the values of the coefficients in the `SSlogis`, i.e. the Asym, the xmid and the scal?

Comment: The code shown does not use 5,12,1 as starting values. It fixes them at those values.

Comment: Thank you for your commend. So how do I rewrite the code correctly? I try the code 
```
R2<-nls(SR~I(Rrefexp(log(Q)*T10)+aEVI+b+SSlogis(VWC,Asym,xmid,scal)), data=srr11AGprC, start=list(Rref=1.72, Q=.66, a=8.47, b=-8.48, ), trace=T) 
```
It says `Error in nls(SR ~ I(Rref * exp(log(Q) * T10) + a * EVI + b + SSlogis(VWC, : parameters without starting value in 'data': Asym, xmid, scal`

Comment: I then run 
`
R2<-nls(SR~I(Rref*exp(log(Q)*T10)+a*EVI+b+SSlogis(VWC,Asym,xmid,scal)), data=srr11AGprC, 
                             start=list(Rref=1.72, Q=.66, a=8.47, b=-8.48, Asym=5, xmid=12, scal=1), trace=T)
`
but the Asym, xmid and scal always show my initial values: 5, 12, 1 without any change.

Comment: Try writing out Asym/(1+exp((xmid-input)/scal)) rather than using SSlogis.